# Edit the value of an attribute inside a serializer Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What I'm trying to do is changing the value of an attribute in the serializer (seemed like the appropriate place to change it).

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'DeferredAttribute'".
```

This is the error that I'm receiving when doing it my way. Any assistance would be most welcomed.

Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price =models.IntegerField
    name=models.CharField(null=True)
```

In a different app I have the other model

```py
class Order_unit(models.Model):
    amount=models.IntegerField
    price=models.IntegerField
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Serializer:

```
from order.models import *
from product.models import *

class OrderUnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price= serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_price')
    class Meta:
        model = Order_unit
        fields = ['order', 'product', 'amount', 'price']

    def get_price(self,Order_unit):
        price= Order_unit.amount*Product.price
        return price
```

Comment: If you're going to give me -1s, I'd love some feedback as well, possibly even some assistance, its not just about voting..

Comment: what is `default_price`  in `Product.default_price`? did you probably mean  to access the `Product.price` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, let me edit that, it is correct on my IDE though but it won't work, gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you want to multiply the amount with the price of a product, update your `get_price` to be:

```py
def get_price(self,order_unit):
    return order_unit.amount * order_unit.product.price # access the price of the product associated with the order_unit object
```

I also noticed that you use `import *` which is not recommended, check out this question [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Comment: God bless you lol... I've been at this for like 3 hours now, I feel so dumb. Thank you so much and I'll definetley have a look at the import * and change that. Cheers

Comment: just to confirm that i understood it correctly, we need to use order_unit becasue thats the parameter of the function right?

Comment: @NoobsCool yes, that's the name you called it, you can call it whatever you want, it's basically the object being serialized

Comment: Ah that's much clearer, thanks again mate^^